# `ps` of specific container from host

Tags: linux, docker, unix, memory, containers

in the host, is there any way to get `ps` of specific container?

if a container having cgroup foo has processes bar, baz, bam
then like `ps --cgroup-id foo` should print the result of `ps` as if in the container(cgroup) as follows:

```
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 bar
   60 root      0:00 baz
  206 root      0:00 bam
```

it doesn't have to be `ps` though, I hope it could be made of just one or two commands.

Thanks!

Comment: sooo `docker exec that_container ps`? `then like ps --cgroup-id foo` Is this XY problem? It's reducing to finding all processes with that cgroup, and then passing htem to `ps`. Also it's add for `cgroup` to be named `foo`, shouldn't it be like `docker-abcdef123123781.scope`? Anyway `having cgroup foo` then just `ps $(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/foo/cgroup.procs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `docker top` command, e.g.:

```
$ docker top 9f2
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD                                                                   
root                20659               20621               0                   Oct08               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;                            
systemd+            20825               20659               0                   Oct08               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process                                                 
systemd+            20826               20659               0                   Oct08               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process                                                 
systemd+            20827               20659               0                   Oct08               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process                                                 
systemd+            20828               20659               0                   Oct08               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process                                                 
systemd+            20829               20659               0                   Oct08               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process                                                 
systemd+            20830               20659               0                   Oct08               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process                                                 
systemd+            20831               20659               0                   Oct08               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process                                                 
systemd+            20832               20659               0                   Oct08               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process
```

Or you can exec into the container if the container ships with `ps`:

```
docker exec $container_name ps
```

And if `ps` isn't included in the container, you can run a different container in the same pid namespace:

```
$ docker run --pid container:9f2 busybox ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
   23 101       0:00 nginx: worker process
   24 101       0:00 nginx: worker process
   25 101       0:00 nginx: worker process
   26 101       0:00 nginx: worker process
   27 101       0:00 nginx: worker process
   28 101       0:00 nginx: worker process
   29 101       0:00 nginx: worker process
   30 101       0:00 nginx: worker process
   31 root      0:00 ps -ef
```